# Angular 4 ngStyle sum works as string not number

Tags: string, angular, typescript, sum

```
<div class="scroll-element-content" [ngStyle]="{'width.px': (this.width + this.trackWidth)}">
```

this.width is 400 and this.trackWidth is 8

the width of .scroll-element-content will be 4008 (because sum is acting like a string)

these variables ar defined as numbers

```
height: number;
width: number;
trackWidth: number;
```

I found a solution to sum it is:

```
<div class="scroll-element-content" [ngStyle]="{'width.px': (this.width - (-this.trackWidth))}">
```

but is ugly, somebody know how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap them both in a `parseInt ( num )`.

However, here is what I typically do:

Declare a const obj that settles the properties, something like:

```
const myStyle = { width : '0px', height : '0px' };
```

'0px' can be any default.

Then you set ngStyle to this object. That keeps all the conditional logic and messy stuff out of your markup. You can also properly doc/annotate the object (something you can't do simply if you set it all in the markup).

When needed, you manipulate that object in your controller, resetting the width (or any style at all) when you need to update the view.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just add them together first in the .ts file and bind that value to the width property?